# General thinking process to prove simple theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

Here is rather simple [proof of Dedekind theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMg5Z.png) [part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBWTZ.png). While it isn't really difficult to understand it when you are reading, where I am struggling is **how** could I to come to this simple proof myself? I mean, what questions could I ask myself to find out that I have to exploit the fact that there can't be to largest numbers in one set? And how could I link this with this one lemma? Are there any universal steps for this? All I could understand that you always have to use some already known theorem or lemma, but it's rarely enough.

This theory is just good example to display my lack of intuition and mental tools required to prove any mathematical theorem, because it uses only one lemma. I am asking this because I am unable to prove any theorem at all, just feel lost and helpless amidst all possible variants and contradictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a proof by contradiction, which is where you assume the negation (that it's not the case...) and then show that this contradicts your assumption. Thus, your assumption must be incorrect.

I would reason through it just like it's said in the proof. You have this theorem that $\beta$ must fall into one of two cases. So choose only one case to examine at a time to simplify things. Here, they choose to examine $\{1\}$. So you start by assuming what's stated in the theorem: there exists some real number $\beta$ that defines the cut and it exists in the lower class. Then you have to show the actual theorem: that $\beta$ must be the greatest in the lower class. Okay, well let's assume it isn't the greatest in the lower class. Well then this means there has to be some number $\alpha_0$ greater than it! And the argument continues. We reach a contradiction since we assumed that $\beta$ defined the cut but found $r$ that's in the lower cut even though it's greater than $\beta$. The details here aren't very important since you said you understand it. Check out [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2632805/268374) post for more details if you're not sure about this contradiction. But the point is that proof by contradiction takes practice, and you probably couldn't go into proving this without starting out working through simpler proofs like "prove that the product of 2 even numbers is even" and then moving onto proof by induction.

I would say that the best way to get good at writing proofs is to first understand the different techniques of proofs, and then read and practice them. A lot. Look at a lot of mathematical literature and see how things get proved such as the Dedekind theorem.